# Custom Taxonomy in plugin and template

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, templates

I have a plugin that I am developing that is using custom post types and taxonomies. My question is this. How can I load the content/theme data from my plugin on to the page when the go to the custom url of the taxonomy?

EDIT

I am trying to use the plugin's template files and not the themes for my custom taxomony.

Comment: Could you be more specific, are you trying to get WordPress to use the plug-in's template files rather than their themes?

Comment: @StephenHarris Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all - **plugins are for generating content, themes are for displaying it**. So really, a plugin shouldn't do this. But there are grey areas - for example in an 'events' related plugin, it would be desirable to display dates, venue etc - things that a WordPress theme wouldn't normally display.

I would suggest

- making the plugin templates over-rideable with templates of the same name in the theme/child theme.
- Being able to 'turn off' plugin forcing of the template.

To alter the template being used you can use the `template_include` filter. This is an example for taxonomy templates, but a similar process is possible for custom post types.

```
add_filter('template_include', 'wpse50201_set_template');
function wpse50201_set_template( $template ){

    //Add option for plugin to turn this off? If so just return $template

    //Check if the taxonomy is being viewed 
    //Suggested: check also if the current template is 'suitable'

    if( is_tax('event-venue') && !wpse50201_is_template($template))
        $template = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__ ).'templates/taxonomy-event-venue.php';

    return $template;
}
```

**Note** it assumes that the plugin templates are in a template sub-folder relative to current director.

#### Logic

This simply checks that the 'event-venue' taxonomy is being viewed. If not it will use the original template.

The `wpse50201_is_template` function will check if the template WordPress has picked from the theme/child-theme is called `taxonomy-event-venue.php` or `taxonomy-event-venue-{term-slug}.php`. If it is - the original template will be used.

This allows users of your plugin to copy them into their theme and edit them, and the plugin will prioritize the theme/child-theme templates. Only if it can't find them does it fall back to the plug-in templates.

```
function wpse50201_is_template( $template_path ){

    //Get template name
    $template = basename($template_path);

    //Check if template is taxonomy-event-venue.php
    //Check if template is taxonomy-event-venue-{term-slug}.php
    if( 1 == preg_match('/^taxonomy-event-venue((-(\S*))?).php/',$template) )
         return true;

    return false;
}
```

I've used this method in a plugin - you can see a working example of the above [here](https://github.com/stephenh1988/Event-Organiser/blob/master/includes/event-organiser-templates.php).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Trying this out it overwrites the entire theme including the head and foot. How can I get it to use the theme but the body content is replaced with mine?

Comment: you just call `get_header()` and `get_footer()` in the custom template.

Comment: Perfect. that worked just as I had hoped. Thank you!! I was wondering if this was even possible

Comment: I think it might be better to use `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__)` instead, otherwise you might run into issues with *allow_url_include*

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'm calling a taxonomy template from a subdirectory within my theme folder. Keep in mind that `taxonomy.php` will need to stay in your root theme directory.

```
function call_taxonomy_template_from_directory(){
    global $post;
    $taxonomy_slug = get_query_var('taxonomy');
    load_template(get_template_directory() . "/templates-taxonomy/taxonomy-$taxonomy_slug.php");
}
add_filter('taxonomy_template', 'call_taxonomy_template_from_directory');
```

For example, my taxonomy is called 'news-category'. The template is located at `wp-content/themes/mytheme/templates-taxonomy/taxonomy-news-category.php`

Comment: The OP's question is how to load these from a Plugin, and this solution does not work for those. It likely does work when templates are loaded from a Theme.